# No signal on TV and Computer Monitor

Tags: raspbmc, hdmi, kodi, connection

I'm trying to get my Raspberry to work on my TV screen and on my computer monitor, however, Whenever I connect through HDMI with my screen I get `No Signal`. I used to get this sometimes and by rebooting and take cables out and put them back in and it worked again. I had the same by using HDMI-DVI to my computer monitor but it would work if I just reboot or take cables out and put them back in. Now when i went back to work with my Raspberry again after like 3 months or so, it worked to DVI monitor perfectly. When I tried to connect my raspberry with my tv monitor I would get `No Signal` whatever I tried before it didn't work. But when I try to switch to HDMI channel I can only switch to it when **BOTH** the raspberry is connected with my TV screen and the raspberry is powered on. So the TV screen does recognize the raspberry. Anyone know how to solve this and what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Raspbian so it may not be exactly the same as your case. But I did have problem with the display when I first set up my Pi.

First thing to try is to change the `/boot/config.txt` file. Look for `hdmi_safe=1`, uncomment it if it is commented. Second one is `config_hdmi_boost=`. Also uncomment it, but if it is already in effect, increase the number (max 7). Reboot to see if it works.

If still not work, enter `tvservice -d edid` and then `edidparser edid`. It will list out all supported resolution of your display, even indicate which one is preferred. Then edit `/boot/config.txt` and set `hdmi_group` and `hdmi_mode` accordingly. You can look up the available options [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md).

Hope it helps. (But then you must have a working display to carry out the `tvservice` part. Editing the `/boot/config.txt` can be done using a PC since it is in the boot partition)

Answer (score 0):

set hdmi_boost in config.txt - all my Pi cards require this to output on any of my TVs over HDMI.  Basically just uncomment the line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a little more information? I had a similar issue that was caused by screen blanking. After a few minutes of no activity on the keyboard or mouse(I had neither connected) the Pi shuts down the display. You can easily tell if this is your issue, if you have a display upon a reboot that goes away a few minutes later this is the culprit. I will post a link to a thread that helped me solve my issue, because there are 3 different fixes depending on how your Pi boots up. Now this applies to Rasbpian, when I use openelec, or Raspbmc this was not an issue.

Let me know what OS(Raspbian,Raspbmc) and how you are handling input(keyboard,ssh), and perhaps I can offer more exact advice.

I found my solution here http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=18200

Comment: I have Raspbmc(as it says in the tags) and I handle input with keyboard. I dont get any display upon reboot.